# How do we declare multiple choice answers (from gform) in one cell (gsheet response) as separate values in an array? (GAS)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi Helpful Contributors,

I have a gform where user can select more than 1 answer. In response sheet, we will see the multiple answers will be printed in one cell of a column separated by comma. For that matter, I have some calculation to do on each answer. So, I was thinking to declare each input separated by comma as an array value so that I can then refer each value by it's index number in that array. Is this possible?
Below is my code that I tried but when I tried to refer back to that array on index[0], the output is still all the values in that same cell, so I think all are still kept as 1 value of array.

```
function mytest(){
var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 
var input=[];
 
var extraitem=sheet.getRange(lastorder,77).getValue(); //this cell keeps the multiple answers : "Change of address, Change of mobile no., Change of vehicle type, Change of license type" 
  input.push(extraitem.split(','));
  
Logger.log("myinput :"+input[0]); // check the value in position 0 is the first among the multiple answers
}
```

Please correct my code. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is the value of `extraitem`? can you do `Logger.log(extraitem)`

Comment: the values of extraitem is string type and could vary from one responder to another in gform. maximum is 4 values. here in this case, I consider all 4 values : "Change of address, Change of mobile no., Change of vehicle type, Change of license type"

Comment: I think my code is wrong when I declared another array to store what is splitted oredi. when I tried your code as per screenshot, I noticed that actually after the split the values automatically become array values in the same var already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you push an array `extraitem.split(',')` into another array `input=[]`. As a result, `input[0]` is the full array `extraitem.split(',')`.

To get the first element of the `extraitem.split(',')` array you can do `Logger.log(input[0][0])` or (preferably) simply ignore the `push` part:

```
function mytest(){
   var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   
   var extraitem=sheet.getRange(lastorder,77).getValue(); 
   var input= extraitem.split(',');     
   Logger.log("myinput :"+input[0]);
}
```

**Demonstration:**

```js
  const extraitem = "Change of address, Change of mobile no., Change of vehicle type, Change of license type";
  const input = extraitem.split(',');
  console.log("myinput :" + input[0]);
```